# Reference View from Within Companion Object - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

My goal is to statically update the state of a view from outside the class (and package). Currently, I have a companion object for the class and a public function inside it to achieve this.

However, when I try to reference a view of the "parent" from within the companion object, the compiler complains about "Unresolved Reference". Does anyone know the correct way to do this? Thanks in advance!

```
class MyActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        fun updateDisplay(message: String) {
            mTextView.text = message // Unresolved reference: mTextView
        }
    }

    @BindView(R.id.my_text_view) lateinit var mTextView: TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity)
        ButterKnife.bind(this)
    }

    // ...

}
```

Comment: There's no nice way to do this. The companion object has no idea of what instances of the class exist, nor can interact with those in any way. You need to have a reference to the activity you're trying to change somehow. (The activity might not even be shown)

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using this, but I will leave it on here, as I learned something in the comments!):

```
class MyActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        // make a reference to the class instance in here
        var instance: MyActivity? = null

        fun updateDisplay(message: String) {
            instance?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.mTextView)?.let{
                it.text = message 
            }
        }
    }

    @BindView(R.id.my_text_view) lateinit var mTextView: TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        instance = this // meaning it will always reference the most recent instance created

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity)
        ButterKnife.bind(this)
    }

    // ...

}
```

Comment: with this you're leaking your activity.

Comment: is that bad? (I am learning myself as well, so very much open for comments)

Comment: for activity leaks see: https://medium.com/@nitinkumargove/what-are-activity-leaks-and-how-they-happen-3895d71b030b 
you're also de facto using a global which is a very discuraged practice.

Comment: Thanks Joozd i was successfully able to reference the view in the class. However, as @al3c pointed out, using a global variable and activity leaking are not worth the trouble. I'll just have to design the project a better way. Thanks guys!